# "25" adicionado após o "%"

Tags: html

Criei um formulário HTML que vai mandar alguns parâmetros para uma página, nesse formulário tem um parâmetro definido como hidden que é o token.

O token tem vários caracteres "%" no meio dele e verifiquei que na página onde retorna o erro TOKEN INVÁLIDO após submeter o formulário está adicionado na URL o número 25 após cada um dos "%".

Alguém já pegou esse tipo de problema?

Segue um exemplo:

```
<form action="url" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="676%anbh%akjk%31">
        <input type="text" name="nome">
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Foi submetido o token `676%anbh%akjk%31` mas na url está como `url?token=676%25anbh%25akjk%2531` observe que tem o número `25` após cada `%`.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp . Acho que vai ter de fazer um string replace dos "25", por uma string vazia ''.

Comment: Faço isso no código que recebe o parâmetro?

Comment: @LaércioLopes isso ocorre pois a a Url não é um bom lugar para ter caracteres especiais, muitos servidores bloqueiam esses caracteres na URL e o próprio navegador vai interpretar essa URL e rodar um "[urlEncode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp)" nela. E o jeito que ele encoda é justamente adicionando % e o código do caractere, por exemplo %20 é o " " (espaço). Adicionalmente, por se tratar de um Token, o mínimo de segurança seria enviar via POST, e provavelmente implementar uma conexão segura.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado @LucasQueirozRibeiro.

Comment: Isso não é problema, é o correto. `%25` é a codificação do símbolo `%` - Se o token está indo incorreto, o problema provavelmente não é aí.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado @Bacco.